# Write a function to open multiple shapefiles in different folders R

Tags: r, gis

I would like to write a function to open multiple shapefiles (there are 46 of them), each stored in its own folder. I'm working with a nonprofit's data and this is how they store it, so I'm writing the code to conform with their data storage practices (I know it's not ideal).

I tried to write this function, and it sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. I'm having problems opening the file (oddly with some shapefiles it works, and for others I get an error). In addition, I don't know how to assign the file to an object.

I start by getting a list of the shapefile folders within the wd:

```
shapefiles <- list.dirs(path = "./StateShapefiles", full.names = FALSE, 
    recursive = FALSE)
```

Then I write my function (the file and the filefolder have the same name):

```
readshapefile <- function(x){
    statename <- deparse(substitute(x))
    filefolder <- paste(wd,statename, sep="/")
    assign(x,readOGR(dsn=filefolder,layer=statename))
}
```

I try to call the function and get this error:

```
readshapefile(alabama)

Error in assign(x, readOGR(dsn = filefolder, layer = statename)) : 
    object 'alabama' not found
```

And then I would like to do something like:

```
for (x in shapefiles){
    readshapefile(x)
}
```

I can't tell if that will work because I can't figure out the earlier part.

I suspect the issues is that readOGR won't take objects as arguments; it only wants strings, but I don't know. If anyone could help with a solution that doesn't involve telling the organization to move their files (unfortunately, that's just not going to happen), that would be great! I can always write 46 lines of readOGR, but that's not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data, its hard to give you good answers. This may be closer to what you need.

```
shapefiles <- list.dirs(path = "./StateShapefiles", full.names = FALSE, 
    recursive = FALSE)

#function reads and returns object for given state
readshapefile <- function(statename){
    filefolder <- paste(getwd(), statename, sep="/")
    # display a message to help with debugging
    cat("Reading ", statename, " from ", filefolder, "\n")
    return(readOGR(dsn=filefolder, layer=statename))
}

#test the function, assigning to an object name
alabama_object <- readshapefile("alabama")

# lapply will call the function once for each state name 
# passing the state name as a parameter
all_shapes <- lapply(shapefiles, readshapefile)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The function works, but the `lapply` doesn't. I also need to assign a name to each opened shapefile (or maybe not?). How do I call up the file to work on it in later parts of my code? The file is not stored as `"alabama"`.

Comment: added a debug message and assignment.  Individual shapefiles can be indexed, for example as `all_shapes[2]`. or with something like `all_shapes[which[shapefiles == "california"]]`